# url rewriting does not return $_GET

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've set some rules for url rewritte on my website.

Actually I'm on localhost

I've set this in .htaccess

```
php_flag output_buffering on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^p/([^/]*)\.html$ /?p=$1 [L]
```

Actualy url rewrite does works (I adde a base href in the header for css, js, and lib php

The trouble I met is that it does not return the $_GET param.

I've written a function for including the pages in the main frame of my document, so we have this

```
function includePage(){
    if(isset($_GET['p'])){
        $page = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['p']);
        if(file_exists('p/'.$page.'.phtml')){
            include('p/'.$page.'.phtml');
        }else{
            include('p/404.phtml');
        }
    }else{
        include('p/accueil.phtml');
    }
}
```

Actualy it does not works it returns to me everytime the else condition.

I've tried to do a `var_dump($_GET['p'])` it returns to me an undefined var

the url looks like this :

index.php/p/realisations so the param $_GET['p'] should be equal to 'realisations' in that case, actualy it does not work.

I do not know where I'm wrong. I've done some reasearch with no success.

anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What URL did you try to test it?

Comment: index.php/p/realisations on my localhost

Comment: The best to escape the URL is not `mysql_real_escape_string()`, it's [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) (the name says it all).

Comment: oh, that's great, I did not know that function thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php/p/([^/.]+)(\.html)?$ ?p=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: it return to me a file that display configuration of the server

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule ^index\.php/p/([^/.]+)(\.html)?$ ?p=$1 [L,NC,QSA]`

Comment: now it works fine, thank you. what If I want to add an additional parameter to the url ? How do I do ?

Comment: Give me an example of what you want to do then I can surely suggest.

Comment: for example sometimes I have p=nameofpage&id=idtobesiplayed

Comment: So you want URL like: `index.php/p/nameofpage/idtobesiplayed` ?

Comment: but id is a param it can be called something else, but how to I $_GET this param ?

Comment: If id is param then my rule already takes care of it since I am using QSA flag therefore every param will be available in `index.php`. Use `$_GET['id']` to access it.

Comment: ok so I just have to call every param with /param/var/param2/var2 ?

Comment: No param is part of query string. So your pretty URL will be like: `/index.php/p/realisations?name=value` OR `/index.php/p/realisations?name=value&foo=bar` etc

Comment: so I can add any param this way ?

Comment: Yes you can any query string with `/index.php/p/something` and it will be carried over to rewritten URL.